# How to increase width of label?

Tags: html, css, label

I am adding a div dynamically.It contains random amount of data that sometimes spreads over more than one lines. Problem is that it becomes conj-gusted in that case.

**`Sample`**
[image]

in other words, i want to increase the line spacing of that label.
Here is code i am adding `label`

```
var m=0;
var ttp = document.getElementById("T_" + (m + 1));
var LH = document.createElement('label');
LH.id = "H_" + element_name + "_" + (m + 1);
var pp = document.createElement('p');
pp.innerHTML = "<br>" + element_name;
LH.appendChild(pp);
ttp.appendChild(LH);
```

Comment: do you mean `line-height: 1em` or more?

Comment: You should show an example of HTML you are creating. It seems that you are not using the `label` element for its defined purpose. You should also describe what you mean by “conj-gusted” (probably “congested”, but this still does not really say what the problem is). If the problem is too small line height, as it seems, then this should be fixed by a simple CSS rule, like `label { line-height: 1.3 }` (but a label should normally be short enough so that it won’t get divided into two or more lines).

Comment: i have marked the answer @JukkaK.Korpela

Comment: It’s still not clear at all what was the *question*. The title refers to width, yet you have accepted an answer that sets line height (in an unnecessarily clumsy and inflexible way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can able to add styles for a particular element at the time of creating. you can assign your styles here: `obj.style.cssText`

```
var LH = document.createElement('label');

//Code for set line height
LH.style.lineHeight = "15px";
LH.id = "H_" + element_name + "_" + (m + 1);
```

Comment: the way you are doing will remove all the inline styles which were present already and apply the line-height.

Comment: I think here only you are creating the element.. then where you are added other inline styles.. here I didn't find other styles for this code

Comment: you are right.. but the OP or other future reader don't know about this and might use the same. it is better to add a class instead or mention what it will do exactly.

Comment: then replace the code with `LH.setAttribute("style","line-height: 15px;");`

Comment: you are doing the same again... you should actually do `LH.style.lineHeight = "15px";`. or add a class, because stylings are meant to be in css but not javascript. I don't mean any bad to you.. I am just explaining how this works. let me know if I am wrong somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Through Javascript u can change the css by this

```
document.getElementById("lableId").style.line-height="20%";
```

or u can set css via

```
$('#LabelID').css('attribute','value');
```

Comment: that is `lineHeight` not `line-height` in javascript.